# Running export_inference_graph.py throws an attribute error

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

So, after training on the cloud, I tried to export the inference graph using the following link:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/exporting_models.md

The code that I used was:

```
python export_inference_graph.py \--input_type image_tensor \--pipeline_config_path samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets \--trained_checkpoint_prefix training\model.ckpt-29809 \--output_directory crop_graph1
```

It throws an error:

> C:\Users\kannan\Desktop\Deep Learning
>   Projects\GCP\models\research\object_detection>python
>   export_inference_graph.py --input_type image_tensor
>   --pipeline_config_path samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets
>   --trained_checkpoint_prefix training\model.ckpt-29809
>   --output_directory crop_graph1 Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "export_inference_graph.py", line 119, in 
>       tf.app.run()   File "C:\Users\kannan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py",
>   line 41, in run
>       flags_passthrough = f._parse_flags(args=args)   File "C:\Users\kannan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\flags.py",
>   line 45, in _parse_flags
>       self._assert_all_required()   File "C:\Users\kannan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\flags.py",
>   line 78, in _assert_all_required
>       self._assert_required(flag_name)   File "C:\Users\kannan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\flags.py",
>   line 74, in _assert_required
>       raise AttributeError('Flag --%s must be specified.' % flag_name) AttributeError: Flag --output_directory must be specified.

Any idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue arises from below line

```
\--trained_checkpoint_prefix training\model.ckpt-29809 \--output_directory crop_graph1
```

this `training\model.ckpt-29809` should have a double quote like

```
"training\model.ckpt-29809"
```

I assume python is treating that extra "-" between ckpt and 29809
Or maybe remove the backslash as it meant for continuous command.

The command should be in one line without "\"

```
python export_inference_graph.py --input_type image_tensor --pipeline_config_path samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets --trained_checkpoint_prefix "training\model.ckpt-29809" --output_directory crop_graph1
```

Comment: I did try what you suggested but it still throws the same error

Comment: Yup! that worked. Earlier, while training locally, it worked with"\". Why is that the case?

Comment: "\" is good if you are issuing a multi-line command so that means that the previous line is not yet done and the succeeding lines are part of the previous lines